# Force a tool version with MSBuild from inside the file?

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I've moved my project over to .NET 4.0 recently, and am having some trouble running the ASP.NET compiler inside of my build.  This doesn't work because MSBuild by default uses an old tools version when running the ASP.NET Compiler.

I've been able to address it my specifying the tools version explicitly (yes, I'm running MSBuild 4.0) like so:

```
msbuild /t:MyTarget /tv:4.0 mybuildfile.msbuild
```

Is there any directive I can use **from within the build file itself** which will allow me to call msbuild in a more plain vanilla fashion like so?

```
msbuild /t:MyTarget mybuildfile.msbuild
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the project `ToolsVersion` to 4.0 in your msbuild file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   ...
</Project>
```