# How come my solution builds in Visual Studio but not from the command line using msbuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

If anyone has any idea where to start troubleshooting this, I'd love to hear it. I just upgraded my project to VS2012, Wix 3.6 and .NET 4.5 and I have like 2000 errors whenever I try to build my using the command line (msbuild): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oQus.png

It builds fine from Visual Studio, but I get a bunch of errors when msbuild is invoked from the command line like this: http://pastie.org/5102451

Comment: did it work at the command line before you added VS2012? are you using the VS2010 command prompt, or the VS2012 command prompt?

Comment: When I refer to using the command prompt, I mean cmd.exe and using the command referenced in my original post (pastie.org link). Sorry if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: and btw, yes it did work from the command line prior to the upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure you are using the right tools version in your msbuild file:

[Force a tool version with MSBuild from inside the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819781/force-a-tool-version-with-msbuild-from-inside-the-file)

This may not be the case, but I often found that this would trip others up in the team when migrating to a new .net runtime and using msbuild.

== Edit ==

Sorry just noticed you are running it DIRECTLY on the command line and not through some build script so the above solution may not be 100% relevant, but it may still be that the version of MSBuild being executed is unable to handle your .net runtime, as all it takes is 1 project to fail building and then all dependent projects will fail giving your 1000s of random errors whereas really there is only 1 meaningful error that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I tried running the command that didn't work (the pastie.org link) with /tv:4.0 and I got the same errors.

Comment: It could be down to your Any CPU type not being valid on the command line, I have had plenty of issues before where I am building as X86 in the IDE but it will try to build x64 on the command line based on the underlying OS, so try changing that to x86. Also confirm that in the build configurations all these projects have the boxes ticked to build for this configuration.